# Devolver un arreglo de 8 bits en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo un programa para un Vúmetro en python donde requiero devolver un arreglo de valores en binario de 8 bits,pero cuando ejecuto mi programa me devuelve el arreglo pero de forma que primero se ejecutan los 8 0's después un 1 con 7 0's, dos 1's con 6 0's,... pero necesito que que primero se ejecuten los 8 0's después en la primera posición se ejecute un 1 y 7 0's y en la tercera ejecución el 1 se muestre en la segunda posicion y asi consecutivamente hasta las 8 posiciones.

Este es mi codigo Python:

```
import time

Array = [18, 23, 24, 25, 12, 16, 20, 21]

def  binario(numero):
    ceros=8-numero

    resultado = []

    for i in range(8): 
       resultado.append(numero & 1)
       numero >>= 1
    return resultado


contador = 0

while True:
     contador = (contador + 1)%256
     print(contador)

     for bit in zip(Array,binario(contador)):
         print(bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu función retorna un array de enteros, en el que cada entero es un bit de la representación binaria del número. Lo devuelve "al revés" en el sentido de que el primer bit del array es el bit de menor peso del resultado.

Así, por ejemplo, si le pasas como parámetro el número 18, que en binario sería 00010010, tu función devuelve la lista `[0, ,1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]` que se puede comprobar que contiene los bits correctos pero "hacia atrás".

Cuando invocas en un bucle a esa función, desde el programa principal, pasándole un entero que se va incrementando (`contador`) lo que obtienes es la representación en binario de todos los números de 0 a 255.

De tu descripción de la pregunta parece que lo que querías más bien es una lista en la que todos los bits estén a 0, salvo uno, que se vaya desplazando de izquierda a derecha. Eso obviamente no es la representación binaria del número.

En este caso puedo entender que el parámetro `numero` que recibe la función podría servir para indicar en qué posición de los 8 bits queremos el 1. Si el parámetro es 0, todos los bits serán 0. Si es 1, el primer bit será 1, si es 2, el segundo bit será 1, etc.

En este caso no veo sentido a pasarle a la función un número mayor de 8.

Esta sería una implementación de la función que buscas, si te he entendido bien:

```py
def  binario(numero):
    resultado = [0] * 8  # Preparamos una lista de 8 ceros
    numero %= 9   # Asegurarse de que numero está entre 0 y 8
    if numero > 0:
      # Cambiamos a 1 un bit de la lista
      resultado[numero -1] = 1
    return resultado

for i in range(9):
  print(i, binario(i))
```

La ejecución produce:

```
0 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
6 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
7 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
8 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```